# addClass removeClass is not working for internet explorer

Tags: jquery, image, internet-explorer, addclass, removeclass

Would anyone know why this would not work in ie? seems to be broken on all versions of IE, no idea why. In every browser but IE it finds the image and removes the hide class and adds the show class.

```
onClickMakeActive("acousticCompression");
onClickMakeActive("Chiropractor");
onClickMakeActive("healthCoaching");
onClickMakeActive("oneOnOne");

function onClickMakeActive(className){  
    $("li."+className+"").click(function(){
        var defaultDescription = $(".defaultDescription");
        if(!defaultDescription.hasClass("hide")){
            defaultDescription.addClass("hide");
        }
        var myThis = $(this);
        makeActive(myThis, className);
        $(".DONTHIDE").show();
    });
}
function makeActive(myThis, className){
    myThis.siblings().removeClass("active");
    myThis.addClass("active");
    myThis.siblings().find(".pointer").removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
    myThis.find(".pointer").removeClass("hide").addClass("show");

    var itemsToToggle = "."+className+"Toggle";
    $(itemsToToggle).siblings().not(".dontHide").removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
    $(itemsToToggle).removeClass("hide").addClass("show");

}
```

here is the HTML just in case

```
<div class="clearfix typeWrapper">
    <ul class="serviceType dontHide">
        <li class="acousticCompression"><a class="acousticCompression servicesTypes">Acoustic Compression</a><span class="pointer hide"></span></li>
        <li class="healthCoaching"><a class="healthCoaching servicesTypes">Health Coaching</a><span class="pointer hide"></span></li>
        <li class="Chiropractor"><a class=" servicesTypes">Chiropractic Care</a><span class="pointer hide"></span></li>
        <li class="oneOnOne"><a class="oneOnOne servicesTypes">Comprehensive Holistic Care</a><span class="pointer hide"></span></li>
    </ul>

    <p class="defaultDescription">carefully selected and extensively trained a team of providers, who are all available to serve you either through his direction or as your direct provider</p>
    <img class="managedHolisticCareToggle serviceTypeImage hide" src="[@RelImageRoot]/PatientIntakeForm/managedHolisticCare.jpg" alt="managed Holistic Care" width="" height="" />
    <img class="acousticCompressionToggle serviceTypeImage hide" src="[@RelImageRoot]/PatientIntakeForm/acousticCompression.jpg" alt="acoustic Compression" width="" height="" />
    <img class="ChiropractorToggle serviceTypeImage hide" src="[@RelImageRoot]/PatientIntakeForm/Chiropractor.jpg" alt="Chiropractor" width="" height="" />
    <img class="healthCoachingToggle serviceTypeImage hide" src="[@RelImageRoot]/PatientIntakeForm/healthCoaching.jpg" alt="health Coaching" width="" height="" />
    <img class="oneOnOneToggle serviceTypeImage hide" src="[@RelImageRoot]/PatientIntakeForm/one-on-one.jpg" alt="one-on-one" width="" height="" />
</div>
```

I am not seeing any errors returning, so I am a bit confused.

link to page in question https://beta.teammotio.com/drdenboer/Patient_Intake

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me. Course i just wrote a quick example and tested on IE9, not your code per say, but works fine as far as i can see

Comment: @user2675751 changing the variable name will have no effect on the code.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: doesn't seem to work. link here in case you need context https://beta.teammotio.com/drdenboer/Patient_Intake

Comment: fyi, `if(!defaultDescription.hasClass("hide")){` isn't necessary.

Comment: That's a creative way to do things? I would just do it like this myself -> http://jsfiddle.net/qxSEf/2/ , but who cares ?

Comment: thanks Kevin, I added it thinking it might have been a part of the problem. Its clear its not :/

Comment: There's nothing obvious wrong with the script, and you said there's no errors, so this could be a problem with the order in which the css rules appear on the stylesheet.

Comment: Sometimes Class is not show in ObjectInspector-F12 but when you trigger: alert( $('#elm').attr('class') ); it show

Answer (score 0):

Looking on your website, it looks like it's not a problem with your code not working, but rather a problem of image size.  Your 5 images have width="1" and height"1" in IE, si I guess there is some other code modifying it.

```
<img width="1" height="1" class="managedHolisticCareToggle serviceTypeImage hide" alt="managed Holistic Care" src="/drdenboer/userfiles/image//PatientIntakeForm/managedHolisticCare.jpg">

<img width="1" height="1" class="oneOnOneToggle serviceTypeImage show" alt="one-on-one" src="/drdenboer/userfiles/image//PatientIntakeForm/one-on-one.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediate thing that comes to my mind is to change

```
$(".DONTHIDE").show();
```

to

```
$(".dontHide").show();
```

These should not be case sensitive, but...